# Getting content between two div tags using Simple Html Dom

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm using Simple HTML Dom to parse text between HTML tags.Everything went well until i faced this challenge.I can easily parse text within div tags but how can I parse text between two div tags.

This is the HTML to be parsed:

```
<div class="album"><b>Album1</b> (1997)</div>
<a href="song11.html" target="_blank">song11</a><br />
<a href="song12.html" target="_blank">song12</a><br />

<div class="album"><b>Album2</b> (1998)</div>
<a href="song21.html" target="_blank">song21</a><br />
<a href="song22.html" target="_blank">song22</a><br />

<div class="album"><b>Album3</b> (1999)</div>
<a href="song31.html" target="_blank">song31</a><br />
<a href="song32.html" target="_blank">song32</a><br />
```

I want the first album title (Album1), its year (1997) and both the song links with their titles in a single array. Then the second album in a second array and the third album in a third array.

Comment: How much you did so far? Do the song item remain same in number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think of it as text between two div nodes, think of it as iterating the div nodes and including some of the a nodes that follow them:

```
$html =<<<EOF
<div class="album"><b>Album1</b> (1997)</div>
<a href="song11.html" target="_blank">song11</a><br />
<a href="song12.html" target="_blank">song12</a><br />
<div class="album"><b>Album2</b> (1998)</div>
<a href="song21.html" target="_blank">song21</a><br />
<a href="song22.html" target="_blank">song22</a><br />
<div class="album"><b>Album3</b> (1999)</div>
<a href="song31.html" target="_blank">song31</a><br />
<a href="song32.html" target="_blank">song32</a><br />
EOF;

require('simple_html_dom.php');
$doc = str_get_html($html);
$albums = array();

foreach($doc->find('div.album') as $div){
  $album = array();
  $album['title'] = $div->find('b', 0)->innertext;
  $album['song1'] = $div->nextSibling()->innertext;
  $albums[] = $album;
}

var_dump($albums);
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. But how to find the number of siblings??? For example album1 has 2 songs and album2 has 3 songs.

Comment: Use a loop. If you need more help start a new question.

Comment: already did. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677003/simple-html-dom-to-edit-html

Comment: what if there are other tags in between divs, such as <p> and so on? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839709/simple-html-dom-find-text-between-divs

Comment: In that case you would do `p b`. [Go here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) to learn how to select elements.