# Simple HTML Dom - find text between divs

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I need to extract the text in between divs here ("The third of four...") - using Simple HTML Dom PHP library.

I have tried everything I think! `next_sibling()` returns the comment, and 
`next_sibling()->next_sibling()` returns the `<br/>` tag. Ideally I would like to get all the text from the end of the first comment and to the next `</div>` tag.

```
<div class="left">
Bla-bla..
<div class="float">Bla-bla...
</div><!--/end of div.float-->
    <br />The third of four performances in the Society's Morning Melodies series features...<a href='index.php?page=tickets&month=20140201'>&lt;&lt; Back to full event listing</a>
</div><!--/end of div.left-->
```

This below prints `<!--/end of div.float-->` - the comment tag.

```
//find content that follows div with a class float. There is a comment in between.
$div_float = $html->find("div.float");
$betweendivs =  $div_float[0]->next_sibling();
$actual_content = $betweendivs ->outertext ;
echo $actual_content;
```

My next step would be getting `innertext` of the div.left and then deleting of all the divs inside of it, but that seems like a major hassle. Is there anything easier I can do?

Comment: You can´t put this text on a span with id and perform a selection by `jQuery` or `document.getElementById`?

Comment: have you used jquery's closest() and child?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in PHP only? Is the document valid xhtml? If so, use something like SimpleXML to load it up as an XML document, then xpath your way to success.

Comment: PHP only and using Simple HTML Dom - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/. This is for purposes of scraping HTML.

Comment: Don't scrape if you can at all help it. Like I said, if it's valid XHTML, it's far more efficient to use an XML parser like SimpleXML

Comment: In `DOMXPath` I'd do `//text()[preceding::comment()[contains(.,"/end of div.float")] and following::comment()[contains(.,"/end of div.left")]]` or something... I wouldn't know what the equivalent in 'simple'htmldom would be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find('text', $index)` to get all the text blocks, where `$index` is the index of the wanted text...

So in this case, it's:

```
echo $html->find('text', 3);

// OUTPUT:
The third of four performances in the Society's Morning Melodies series features...
```

You can read more in the [`Manual`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find)

**EDIT:**

Here's a working code:

```
$input = '<div class="left">
Bla-bla..
<div class="float">Bla-bla...
</div><!--/end of div.float-->
    <br />The third of four performances in the Society\'s Morning Melodies series features...<a href="index.php?page=tickets&month=20140201">&lt;&lt; Back to full event listing</a>
</div><!--/end of div.left-->';

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($input);

// Using $index
echo $html->find('text', 3);

echo "<hr>";

// Or, it's the 3rd element starting from the end
$text = $html->find('text');
echo $text[count($text)-3];

// Clear DOM object
$html->clear();
unset($html);

// OUTPUT
The third of four performances in the Society's Morning Melodies series features...
The third of four performances in the Society's Morning Melodies series features...
```

<kbd>[Working DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qcy-gcd)</kbd>

Comment: unfortunately, it's unknown how many text blocks there will be on various other pages. Useful tip though.

Comment: @Natalia Isnt it the last text of your `<div class="left">` ? then you know where it is !

Comment: sorry, but echo $html->find('text', 3); doesn't actually output anything here. Anything else I should try?

Comment: @Natalia, demo added :)

Comment: cool. I wished in worked on the real page though. I just looped through all text blocks and there are over 300 including all kind of javascript snippets and of course the placement of the needed text block is going to be different on every single page. The `[count($text)-3]; ` will get handy one day though! :)

Answer (score 2):

why dont you use ->plaintext on div.class? It outputs the text as needed.

```
$html->find("div[class=left]")->plaintext;
```

Martti

Comment: Because I just need the portion starting at <!--/end of div.float--> and don't need a whole page of content before that. I wish I could hook on that comment tag somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think Simple HTML Dom does not provide tools to do this, as there is no "get before " or "get after" types of commands. If I am wrong, please let me know.

Comment: In addition to prev_sibling and next_sibling, css has `+` and `~`. Unfortunately simple doesn't support it. You might consider switching to [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/) which does

Comment: @pguardiario, wow, that's pretty new (4 days) and seems to be perfect supporting CSS3... I'll wait for a while though untill getting enough feedbacks before replacing simpleDom, i'll also try to test it soon... Thanks for the link :)

Comment: @pguardiario - I'd like to play with it "Advanced HTML Dom" some more, is there a list of selectors it supports?

Comment: The list of css3 selectors is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/), some of them wouldn't make sense like E:hover or a:visited. But the ones that do should be working.

Comment: I can't even get started. Posted a message in forum on SourceForge.